# How can I write the vertices of a 2d polygon to a text file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to save the vertices of a 2D polygon to a text file.

e.g. i have drawn two flat squares on the X-Y plane, which i have named "Square 1" and "Square 2", locations of their vertices are:
Square 1: (1,1) (1,0) (0,0) (0,1) 
Square 2: (4.2,4.2) (4.2,3.2) (3.2,3.2) (3.2,4.2) 

I would like to save these vertices to a simple text file in this format:
Square 1: 1 1, 1 0, 0 0, 0 1 
Square 2: 4.2 4.2, 4.2 3.2, 3.2 3.2, 3.2 4.2

Any help is welcome, Thanks!

after some more googling i'm finally getting somewhere!

```
import bpy  

current_obj = bpy.context.active_object  


    print("="*40) # printing marker  
    for face in current_obj.data.polygons:  
        verts_in_face = face.vertices[:]  
        for vert in verts_in_face:
            local_point = current_obj.data.vertices[vert].co
            world_point = current_obj.matrix_world * local_point
            print('%.2f %.2f, ' % (world_point.x, world_point.y), end='', flush=True )
    print("")
```

this outputs to the console in the format i want, however printing to a file in the for loop doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep it similar to what you have already scripted.

```
import bpy

current_obj = bpy.context.active_object
f = open("d:\\test.txt", 'w')  # use 'a' to append
for face in current_obj.data.polygons:
    for vert in face.vertices[:]:
        local_point = current_obj.data.vertices[vert].co
        world_point = current_obj.matrix_world * local_point
        f.write('x: %.2f\t y: %.2f\n' % (world_point.x, world_point.y))
f.close()
```

Comment: `face.vertices[:]` creates a full copy of the list of vertices. Why is that necessary?

Also, you can use `f.write('x: %.2f y: %.2f\n' % (world_point.x, world_point.y))` instead of the manual rounding and string conversion.

Comment: @dr.Sybren Thank you Dr. Sybren. updated & removed some trailing white spaces.

Comment: Awesome, cheers! I'll see how that goes tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: Thanks to your script i figured out where i was going wrong when writing to a file, i would use "d:\test.txt" not a double backslash.

Now i just have a permission error :-) but that's ok.

Comment: The double backslash is necessary  because a single backslash is a special escape character. See [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your planes as FBX. In the export dialog, tick *Selected Objects* and switch the version to *FBX 6.1 ASCII*.

Now you have a simple text file, although with much overhead. In there you will find a line similiar to this:

`Vertices: -1.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,2.000000,-2.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,0.000000`

I got this result from exporting a simple standard plane where I moved one edge. The vertices are all in the order x,y,z. With search and replace in your text editor, you could delete all `0.000000`, which are the z-values. They are all 0 and thus easily to distinguish from x- and y-values, since all your planes are on the x-y-plane.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, while this does get the data i need into a text file, the overhead and the inclusion of the Z values would wreak havoc on my subsequent programs that require the polygons, and adding another script to clean it up the FBX seems like a doubling of work for no gain.

I would much rather have a single python script that outputs the vertices into a text file.